# Extending multiple interfaces in aura:application

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

How do I extend multiple interfaces in aura:application.

I want to use ltng:out and force:slds in the same app and expose the app on a public website. As a workaround I downloaded the slds class into static resource referenced through ltng: require for now

When I try to save this code in developer console:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds,ltng:outApp" access="GLOBAL">
    <aura:dependency resource="c:casesearch"/>
</aura:application>
```

I get the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't. Lightning does not support multiple inheritance. An app can be either a Lightning Out app **or** a SLDS app. A LO app is only meant to resolve dependencies, not execute as an actual app. In your use case, you'd want two apps: one as a LO app to define dependencies, and a SLDS app for running as a standalone app.

Comment: Got it, so I guess my workaround of using SLDS as static resource will help me get what I want for now(Yet to test on a public site if all this will tie together)

Comment: Or I can have app2 be a dependent app on app1 using aura:dependency

Comment: @Rao use two different apps if need be. There are performance implications of using a non-LO app as a LO app.